# Why does gcc hate my simple makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, flex-lexer

I have the following makefile that gcc doesn't like:

```
blah.exe:lex.yy.o
    gcc –o blah.exe lex.yy.o
lex.yy.o:lex.yy.c
    gcc  –c lex.yy.c
lex.yy.c:blah.lex
    flex blah.lex
```

If I delete everything except the orginal blah.lex file, then I get this error when I run make:

```
flex blah.lex
gcc  ûc lex.yy.c
gcc: ûc: No such file or directory
make: *** [lex.yy.o] Error 1
```

Now if i execute the following the commands in this order, it all works without errors and compiles.

```
flex blah.lex    
gcc  –c lex.yy.c
gcc –o blah.exe lex.yy.o
```

Following this, if I run make, it says:

```
make: `blah.exe' is up to date.
```

This is normal response if the *.o and *.exe files exist. But why wont 'make' work when these files need to be created.

Note: I have put Tabs in the makefile. flex is a tool that generates lex.yy.c based on the contents of blah.lex

Comment: This has to be some problem of the character encoding of the Makefile. Try to use any editor that allows you to show actual characters, such as vi, or notepad++, for example.

Comment: I used notepad++ for creating the makefile

Answer (score 10):

If you copied the text directly from the `Makefile`, here is your problem:

Instead of a simple dash (ASCII 45, Unicode U+002D) you have an en-dash (cp1252 0x96, Unicode U+2013) in the `gcc -o ...` and `gcc -c ...` lines. Replace them with simple dashes.

To see whether you succeeded, use the following command:

```
cat Makefile | tr -d '\r\n\t -~' | hexdump -C
```

This will extract all "weird" bytes from the Makefile and print them to you in a hexdump. Ideally the output of this command should be this:

```
00000000
```

In your case the output is probably:

```
00000000  ef bb bf e2 80 93 e2 80  93                       |.........|
00000009
```

This means that the file is UTF-8 encoded (the first three bytes tell you that), and there are two other UTF-8 characters in it: two times `e2 80 93`, which is the UTF-8 encoding for U+2013, the en-dash.

Comment: Oh. Love windows encodings... :)

Comment: A quick look at http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_850 confirmed that suspicion. The Makefile is encoded in CP1252, and the console window is using Codepage 850, in which the number 0x96 represents a `û`, exactly the character you posted.

Comment: Thanks so much. The dashes were the problem. When I created the makefile, I had copy and pasted a makefile example out of a Word document which had the wrong kind of dashes in it.

Comment: You also need to watch out for tab characters.  Makefiles require actual tab (ASCII HT, `\t`) characters; spaces won't do.  Copy-and-paste might expand tabs to spaces if you're not careful.  (This might depend on what version of `make` you're using.)